# Windows 7 Sending SSDP M-SEARCH Packets Even Though UPnP and SSDP Services Are Disabled

Tags: upnp, ssdp

I have a small Windows 7 business *workgroup* network (no Domain Controller, not using Homegroup) that I am trying to eliminate SSDP traffic from.  I've disabled the SSDP Discovery and UPnP Device Host services on each computer and restarted each computer.  When I use Wireshark to capture packets from one of the computers I see a SSDP packet sent every 90 seconds or so from each computer on the network with the following information:

```
Simple Service Discovery Protocol
    M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\n
    HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900\r\n
    ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1\r\n
    MAN: "ssdp:discover"\r\n
    MX: 2\r\n
    \r\n
    [Full request URI: http://239.255.255.250:1900*]
    [HTTP request 1/2]
    [Next request in frame: 2649]

    MAN: "ssdp:discover"\r\n
    MX: 2\r\n
    \r\n
    [Full request URI: http://239.255.255.250:1900*]
    [HTTP request 1/2]
    [Next request in frame: 2649]
```

This issue is covered in this Server Fault [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/64884/network-flooded-with-m-search-packets-what-does-it-mean).  I tried the registry edit suggested by Josh on Oct 3 '14 in that question but the SSDP packets keep getting sent.  I know that these packets are searching for an IP gateway device.  I've disabled UPnP in my IP router. Can someone tell me what is generating these packets?  Can I disable whatever is creating the packets or is this something that is normal behavior?

Comment: From an elevated command prompt run "netstat 1 -a -o >`path`\netstat.txt" (without the quotes) where `path` is the path to a folder of your choice. Let that run for a few minutes then terminate it. Review the generated netstat text file and find the traffic in question. Look at the PID (process ID) for the traffic. Then launch Task Manager and find that PID. That will be the process that's generating the traffic.

Comment: Thanks @joeqwerty for the tip!  I'll give that a try and report back.

Comment: @joeqwerty you are brilliant!  Your suggestion worked perfectly!  If you would provide your comment as the answer to my question I'll select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an elevated command prompt run:

> netstat 1 -a -o >**path**\netstat.txt

where **path** is the path to a folder of your choice. Let that run for a few minutes then terminate it. Review the generated netstat text file and find the traffic in question. Look at the PID (process ID) for the traffic. Then launch Task Manager and find that PID. That will be the process that's generating the traffic.